# Double import in grok

Tags: python, grok

This is a normal case of mutual import. Suppose you have the following layout

```
./test.py
./one
./one/__init__.py
./one/two
./one/two/__init__.py
./one/two/m.py
./one/two/three
./one/two/three/__init__.py
./one/two/three/four
./one/two/three/four/__init__.py
./one/two/three/four/e.py
./one/two/u.py
```

And you have

test.py

```
 from one.two.three.four import e
```

one/two/three/four/e.py

```
from one.two import m
```

one/two/m.py

```
print "m"
import u
```

one/two/u.py

```
print "u"
import m
```

When you run the test.py program, you expect, of course:

```
python test.py
m
u
```

Which is the expected behavior. Modules have already been imported, and they are only once. In Grok, this does not happen. Suppose to have the following app.py

```
import os; import sys; sys.path.insert(1,os.path.dirname( os.path.realpath( __file__ ) ))
import grok
from one.two.three.four import e

class Sample(grok.Application, grok.Container):
    pass
```

what you obtain when you run paster is:

```
$ bin/paster serve parts/etc/deploy.ini
2009-10-07 15:26:57,154 WARNING [root] Developer mode is enabled: this is a security risk and should NOT be enabled on production servers. Developer mode can be turned off in etc/zope.conf
m
u
m
u
```

What's going on in here ?

from a pdb stack trace, both cases are imported by martian:

```
    /Users/sbo/.buildout/eggs/martian-0.11-py2.4.egg/martian/core.py(204)grok_package()  
  -> grok_module(module_info, grokker, **kw)                                             
    /Users/sbo/.buildout/eggs/martian-0.11-py2.4.egg/martian/core.py(209)grok_module()   
  -> grokker.grok(module_info.dotted_name, module_info.getModule(),                      
    /Users/sbo/.buildout/eggs/martian-0.11-py2.4.egg/martian/scan.py(118)getModule()     
  -> self._module = resolve(self.dotted_name)                                            
    /Users/sbo/.buildout/eggs/martian-0.11-py2.4.egg/martian/scan.py(191)resolve()       
  -> __import__(used)
```

The only difference between the first case and the second one is that the first shows the progressive import of e and then of m. In the second case it directly imports m.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Does grok do automatic code reloading? The same thing happens in Werkzeug when use_reloader=True.

Comment: Yes, but not in my case. you have to add a specific switch to perform reloading, and in any case it would not explain the persistence of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could possibly be a side-effect of the introspection Grok does, I'm not sure.

Try to put a pdb.set_trace() in m, and check at the stack trace to see what is importing the modules.

Comment: It appears that it's due to my strategy to import the package. I'm working around it, but still it's a rather anomalous behavior. I found it out because one of the modules pushes an entry in a dict that raises if a duplicate is introduced, and when the second import happens, I get an exception.